# Leaking Power Steering Rack

Tags: power-steering

The Honda dealership service department advised the power steering rack was leaking badly on my 2008 Honda CRV.  It has 103,000 miles on it.  Honda advised on a scale of 1 - 10, the leak was a 7.  I had taken it in for an oil change.

A family-owned transmission company inspected the car's undercarriage and checked steering fluid levels.  The fluid levels were normal and there were no visible leaks.  I looked myself and saw nothing.

Could there be an internal leak that is not visible?  There are no steering noises, burning smells, or tightness in the steering wheel.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You monitor the reservoir, check and see if there is any discoloration, fluid loss, or any particulates. 
If any of the above is true, there is a problem. We'll diagnose it further. But for now just keep it simple.

Keep a big flat cardboard or any paper sheet under the CR-V's steering rack to spot any leaks. Do this while it's parked overnight. Following morning, start it, let it idle, turn the steering wheel full to the left and right 10 to 15 times. Come out and inspect for any leaks on that board underneath.